# How to remember screen position in Geometry Nodes Editor?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

Every time I switch between different geometry nodes groups node editor loses my screen position. It's very annoying. I just want to save space location for each geonodes group.

Do you know how to solve this issue?
Maybe some preferences or addons?

Comment: The problem could probably be described more accurately as "keeping" the screen position. The same happens in the 3D view as well. Toggling collections on and off doesn't influence the 3D viewport camera, just like toggling geometry nodes on and off doesn't influence the 2D geo grid camera. Are you aware of the NumpadComma hotkey to focus on selection?

Comment: or (Numpad '.' on US or UK keyboard mappings)

Comment: At this moment Node Editor uses one screen space for every graph. That's why when I left one graph in a specific (convenient for me) location and switch to another graph I get the wrong location. I am sure more comfortable for everyone's situation when you left one graph, location, and scale saved for this graph end restore when you come back